# Area between curves $y=x$ and$ y=x^2-2$

Tags: calculus

I have to find the area between the curves for $y=x$ and $y=x^2-2$.

I found the intercepts to be -1 and 2. And the f(x) that goes into my integral to be $x-x^2-2$ Evaluating at -1 and 2 I found $-\frac{14}{3}$ and $\frac{17}{6}$. $$-\frac{14}{3} - \frac{17}{6} = -7.5$$

That's what I got but it's not showing as being right, I've tried multiple other things getting everything from -1.5 to -4.5 and weird fraction, and I'm out of things to try now. Above is the one of the ways I tried that I think is closest to being correct, following the examples.

Comment: Because $f(x)-g(x) = x - (x^2-2) = x- x^2 +2$

Comment: Thanks. Guess I've been at this too long again, missing stupid things like that.

Comment: A sign is not a stupid thing. It is a big deal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you find the $x$-intercepts, then since $x \geq x^2-1$ on $[-1,2]$, we have the area between the two curves to be $A = \displaystyle \int_{-1}^2 x dx-\int_{-1}^2 (x^2-2) dx = 4.5$.